# VBA code to protect worksheet but allow filtering

Tags: excel, vba, protected, autofilter

I have a worksheet where i want to limit changes made by users but also allow columns to be grouped so i used the following code.  I then realised i can't filter on the protected sheet so amended the code but it's still not allowing to filter and not sure where i have gone wrong as new to vba

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   MsgBox "File updated for March 23"
    With Sheets("March 23")
        .Protect AllowFiltering:=True
        .Protect Password:="Secret", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        .EnableOutlining = True
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can allow the users to filter the data by setting `AllowFiltering:=True`, however, you will need to activate the filter (show the filter buttons) *before* the sheet is protected as this command is not available on a protected sheet:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Sheets("March 23")
        If Not .AutoFilterMode then .AutoFilter
        .Protect AllowFiltering:=True, _
                 Password:="Secret", _
                 UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        .EnableOutlining = True
     End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but it’s still the same that the filter button is there but I cannot select it to use the filter

Comment: I haven't noticed that you call the `.Protect` twice. You should call it only once and set all parameter, else the 2nd `Protect` will overwrite the 1st and the `AllowFiltering` is gone. See my update.